# List item not formating properly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

`<li>` in this  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JbXHY/1/) doesnt format as I would like to.
The last one which goes 2-line starts right under the `"<li> dot"` (white background is where the text normaly begins).

The question is: How do I force it to rather start a little bit on right? (Just the same position where the upper line starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your HTML is correct. You didn't have `<ul></ul>` and didn't close your `<li>` tags.
I've edited the styles a bit just to show you the results.

http://jsfiddle.net/JbXHY/3/

Comment: Oh, many thanks. Didnt know I have to end <li> tage o.O

Answer (score 1):

Switch your `div` to a `ul` and change your `background` color to a `border` like so:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="ram">

    <li> zdar</li>
    <li> cau </li>
    <li> hey</li>
    <li> jak se mas ty mala slapoto? doufam, ze ne moc dobre :D </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ram {
    border: 10px solid red;
    width: 150px;

}

li {
    color: red;
    background: white;
}
```

NOTE: Please use correct syntax for HTML, or else you will not get your expected results. You can use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) as a great resource for ensuring you are using the correct syntax for your HTML elements.

### **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbXHY/4/)**

Comment: Sure thing, I would stop using background and just use border, it's the same thing and you cannot go wrong with it.

Comment: Well it was added just to show where the text starts and where I want it to start :) Not in any way gonna use it instead of border.

Comment: Gotcha, still, in this context, you should use 'border' to see the border of the element versus using background.

Comment: Ah, yeah you are right :) I didnt realize that. I started with just red background but then I wanted to highlight the text formating so I just added another background to the text.
You are right I could have done that using border ;)